# LUIS apps created on eu.luis.ai not showing on my Azure Portal

Tags: azure, service, bots, azure-language-understanding

I created 2 LUIS apps about a month ago on eu.luis.ai, and they have been working just fine with the Bot they are linked to, but it seems that I have hit some sort of quota on LUIS requests. I think upgrading my plan to a higher tier would resolve the problem, but I can't find the app on my azure portal, and I can't find a way to change the plan from eu.luis.ai either.

You can see my LUIS apps here (eu.luis.ai)

[image]

You can see my Azure apps here, the only cognitive service appearing is QNAMaker

[image]

Does anybody have the same problem ? I am 100% sure I'm logged in with the same account on both websites.

Answer (score 2):

I found what was wrong : when you first start using LUIS, you can create apps on luis.ai without creating them on your Azure portal. They come with starter keys that expire after a month or so. You then have to create a LUIS app on the Azure portal, and add the newly generated key to your existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where I had my LUIS app working with a Speech Recognition service key, and it stopped working after a month. I had to add a new LUIS service on my Azure portal and use that key instead.